# PDO insert and retrieve in same call

Tags: php, pdo

On page load, I am using Ajax to call a PHP script.  This script inserts some URL variables into my database, but after this, I then want to query the database and return some data.  So far I have this

```
try {

    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=" . DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME . "", DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO " . DB_TABLE . "(some_id, some_answer) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $userData['some_id']);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $userData['some_answer']);

    if($stmt->execute()) {
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("select * from " . DB_TABLE . "where some_id NOT 0 AND some_answer NOT 0");
        $res = $stmt->execute();
        $rowset = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } else {
        echo json_encode("failure");
    }

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo json_encode("failure");
}
```

If no URL params are present, I insert a 0 into the database for `some_id` and `some_answer`.  With the select statement, I am trying to retrieve all rows where these two fields are not 0.

With what I currently have, I am getting the error Syntax error or access violation.  What is the best way to retrieve the data once I insert it?  some_answer will be a value between 1 - 4 once the 0 are removed, my overall aim is to return the count of each answer.  So I was thinking of returning an array or something that shows there are 8 instances of some_answer being 1, 7 where some_answer is 2 etc.

Thanks

Comment: _"I am getting the error Syntax error"_ - what _exact_ error do you get? In pdo or in php?

Comment: I guess you'll need a space after the table name (both queries)

Comment: To get the count you can group by some_answer